# Azure web app have slow and unwarm loads (30s+ load)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have a very big problem with an Azure Webapp and would like to hear suggestions.

**What we experience:**

When I goto our website it's quite fast. The average load is around 1 second and respond as expected.

However, once pr. 10-20 minutes, we get a very cold load - where it's 30-60 seconds+.

This would make sense if the website didn't have visitors and it was cold, but we have 10+ visitors online at the website all business hours with 3-5 requests pr minute at a minimum.

This extra load is completely unacceptable of course.

Any ideas?

**Our setup:**

We have two azure web-apps. One for production and one for develop.

The production is a "STANDARD SMALL", with auto scale when CPU hits 65-85%.

We database is S2 with 10 gb.

It's a quite simple standard ASP.NET MVC site with some texts, forms and a few remote connections.

The only "non-standard" is 3 million indexed pages that looks into a database (page load is around 1s). This receives a lot of visitors from Google. We also receive some crawls from Google as we have a sitemap with 3mio+ pages.

**Data from monitor:**

EDIT: data from new monitor.

[image]

Web-app:

[image]

Database:

[image]

**The configurations:**

Production web-app:

[image]

Database:

[image]

**Our attempts:**

1: Always on.

We have tried always on multiple times, but then sometime within the first 30 min  to 6 hours, the site just goes down and doesn't come back**. This is of course a huge problem and is not a solution.

2: Running on a VM.

We have a pretty stable and fine setup on a VM on Azure (4gb RAM) which worked ok. We had quite slow responses, but it worked decent. However, we would like to use the web app to "outsource" the scaling and platform to Azure - we just cannot accept this speed :)

**

It goes unresponsive forever until a timeout. I have tried two scenarioes: one where stopping and starting web-app worked, a second where I had to do a redeploy

Comment: When you turned on "Always On", how does the site go down? When you say it doesn't come back, do you mean you have to do a full deployment to make your site up again?

Comment: @juvchan Thanks for asking that question.
It goes unresponsive forever until a timeout. I have tried two scenarioes: one where stopping and starting web-app worked, a second where I had to do a redeploy.

Comment: your experience is very interesting and useful to learn.

Comment: Did you by change monitor the Azure SQL Instance and check the Connections (this can be done on the portal)? S2 has a max of [120 concurrent connections](http://blogs.technet.com/b/latam/archive/2015/06/01/how-to-deal-with-the-limits-of-azure-sql-database-maximum-logins.aspx), if you are hitting that max regularly, all other connection attempts will timeout.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I tried to add the dashboard of connections. It doesn't look like I hit max as far as I can see (? I could be wrong).

Comment: @juvchan when you see these data from the monitor - does it look normal to you? :-)

Comment: When you say "Always On" is that in the context of Azure SQL Database?

Comment: @JosephIdziorek No, that is my web-app. I did not know you can put the Azure SQL database off?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard Your DTU Percentage is a bit high, do you by chance notice it nearing 100% on the times you have the Timeouts?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard and what about scaling? Do you see your App scaling up when you have the cold loads?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Unfortunately not, I can see here: http://prntscr.com/a4e74f - that it's always 1.

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard DTU Percentage in your metrics is not hitting 100%?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Nope, so I don't think it's a scaling problem per say. But we can still see the crazy loads from the frontend when we access website :-) So problem is not in scaling I think

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard I was wondering if it was the DTU because if you hit 100% DTU, all other requests to the DB are either denied or timedout, and maybe that was the time when you were experiencing the slow response on the website. Not scaling-related :)

Comment: To help isolate if it's SQL DB causing the problems, please use the new portal.azure.com and have a look at the DTU consumption there.  The older portal only shows 5 minute average DTU consumption and the new portal shows 15 second average DTU consumption for the last hour.  Please post a screen shot of the new portal, and what we are looking for is a spike in DTU consumption every 10-20 minutes

Comment: @guyhay_MSFT Thanks for your answer - it seems it stays on average of ~50% on most times but few peaks on 80-90%. I think a reasonable test would be to upgrade the database to 2x DTU - I will do that. However, all metrics seem reasonable i my mind. I am thinking: could it be a DNS problem? I have the problem when I also goto static pages with no or very limited DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

The solution wasn't just in one place, but in multiple places.

**Let me try to dive in.**

The main challenge was the 3 million pages we have indexed. Google crawls between 50-150k pages pr day, which we could see in Google Webmaster tools:

[image]

99.9% Of these pages were a unique type of address pages. I dived into these, and found out these took 1.5-2s on default (!). It was even slow when running towards test.

Step #1 was to make a new index and optimize the code. 5x Performance improvement there.

Now, that doesn't solve the issue by itself. I also upgraded both the database to the new S3... Didn't solve issue totally (but still better).

I also upgraded our Azure Web App to the 7gb version - and THEN things started to perform.

However, we still had a small issue every 30th minute. I went onto our VM and found an old console job that kept some content in order.... I paused that job.

Neither of these findings could stand alone - but after all these were fixed - we're good again and website responds acceptable!

Hurray!

Answer (score 4):

To help further isolate what the bottleneck is, could you please use the new Ibiza portal at http:portal.azure.com.

The older portal, screenshots above, is showing 54-minute averages.  Obviously with 5-minute averages and the DTUs at ~80% there are likely to be periods where all of the DTUs are consumed and that could be the bottleneck.

Using the new portal, these DTU graphs are 15-second averages and this finer granularity could point to the bottleneck.  Can you change to the new portal and paste some more graphs?

Thanks Guy

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it seems it stays on average of ~50% on most times but few peaks on 80-90%. 

I think a reasonable test would be to upgrade the database to 2x DTU - I will do that.

However, all metrics seem reasonable i my mind. I am thinking: could it be a DNS problem? I have the problem when I also goto static pages with no or very limited DB.